# Problema de herencia C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

estaba creando un programa mediante herencia. En el programa tengo un clase base que se llama FiguraGeometrica y de ella se deriva Polygon, de donde se derivan Rectangle y Triangle. Después está la clase ColeccionFiguras la cual tiene un arreglo de punteros de FiguraGeometrica. 
**ColeccionFiguras**

```
#ifndef ColeccionFiguras_h
#define ColeccionFiguras_h
#include "FiguraGeometrica.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//clase control
class ColeccionFiguras{
    protected:
        FiguraGeometrica *pColeccion[10];
        int cantidad;
    public:
        ColeccionFiguras(){
        }
        ColeccionFiguras(int pCantidad){
            cantidad = pCantidad;
        }
        void setCantidad(int pCantidad){
            cantidad = pCantidad;
        }
        void setColeccionAt(int idx, FiguraGeometrica &figura){
            pColeccion[idx] = &figura;
            cout<< pColeccion[idx] <<endl;
        }
        int getCantidad(){
            return cantidad;
        }
        FiguraGeometrica* getColeccionAt(int idx){
            return pColeccion[idx];
        }
};

#endif /*ColeccionFiguras_h*/
```

**FiguraGeometrica**

```
#ifndef FiguraGeometrica_h
#define FiguraGeometrica_h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//clase base abstracta (pura)
class FiguraGeometrica{
    public:
        virtual int area()=0;
};

#endif /*FiguraGeometrica_h*/
```

**Polygon**

```
#ifndef Polygon4_h
#define Polygon4_h
#include "FiguraGeometrica.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon: public FiguraGeometrica{
    protected:
        int width, height;
    public:
        Polygon(int width, int height){
            this->width = width;
            this->height = height;
        }
        void setValues (int a, int b){
            width=a;
            height=b;
        }
        virtual int area()=0;

        void printArea(){
            cout<< this->area()<<'\n';
        }
};
#endif /* Polygon4_h */
```

**Rectrangle**

```
#ifndef Rectangle4_h
#define Rectangle4_h
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon4.h"
using namespace std;

class Rectangle: public Polygon{
    protected:
        int diagonal;
    public:
        //constructor herencia
        Rectangle(int diagonal, int width, int height): Polygon (width, height){
            this->diagonal = diagonal;
        }

        int getDiagonal(){
            return diagonal;
        }

        int area(){
            return (width*height);
        }
};
#endif /* Rectangle4_h */
```

**Triangle**

```
#ifndef Triangle4_h
#define Triangle4_h
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon4.h"
using namespace std;

class Triangle: public Polygon{
    public:
        //constructor herencia
        Triangle(int width, int height): Polygon(width, height){
        }

        int area(){
            return (width*height/2);
        }
};
#endif /* Triangle4_h */
```

El main es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Triangle4.h"
#include "Rectangle4.h"
#include "ColeccionFiguras.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ColeccionFiguras coleccion(2);
    Rectangle rect(2,5,5);
    Triangle trgl(4,5);

    FiguraGeometrica *pFiguraGeometrica = &rect;
    FiguraGeometrica *pFiguraGeometrica1 = &trgl;

    coleccion.setColeccionAt(0, *pFiguraGeometrica);
    coleccion.setColeccionAt(1, *pFiguraGeometrica1);

    for(int i=0; i<coleccion.getCantidad(); i++){
            cout<< coleccion.getColeccionAt(i)->area()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El programa funciona bien, pero ahora debo incluir otra clase que se deriva de FiguraGeometrica llamada Elipse y una clase Circulo que se deriva de Elipse, las he escrito de esta forma, pero no se si son correctas:

**Elipse**

```
#ifndef Elipse_h
#define Elipse_h
#include "FiguraGeometrica.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Elipse: public FiguraGeometrica{
    protected:
        int semieje_a, semieje_b;
    public:
        Elipse(int semieje_a, int semieje_b){
            this->semieje_a = semieje_a;
            this->semieje_b = semieje_b;
        }
        void setValues(int smayor, int smenor){
            semieje_a = smayor;
            semieje_b = smenor;
        }
        virtual int semi()=0;
        void printEjes(){
            cout<<this->semieje_a<<endl;
            cout<<this->semieje_b<<endl;
        }

};
#endif /* Elipse_h */
```

**Circulo**

```
#ifndef Circulo_h
#define Circulo_h
#include "Elipse.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circulo: public Elipse{
    protected:
        int radio;
    public:
        Circulo(int radio, int semieje_a, int semieje_b): Elipse(semieje_a, semieje_b){
            this->radio = radio;
        }
        int semi(){
            radio==semieje_a==semieje_b;
            return radio;
        }
};
#endif /* Cirulo_h */
```

Lo que debo hacer es incluir instancias de estas clases en el main como se hizo con Rectangle y Triangle, y ademas debo imprimir solo el area de los Polygon y solo los semiejes de las Elipse. 
Lo que intenté hacer es hacer un dynamic_cast de esta forma:

```
    int main(){
    ColeccionFiguras coleccion(2);
    Rectangle rect(2,5,5);
    Triangle trgl(4,5);
    Elipse elps(6,4);
    Circulo crcl(3,3,3);

    FiguraGeometrica *pFiguraGeometrica = &rect;
    FiguraGeometrica *pFiguraGeometrica1 = &trgl;
    FiguraGeometrica *pFiguraGeometrica2 = &elps;
    FiguraGeometrica *pFiguraGeometrica3 = &crcl;

    coleccion.setColeccionAt(0, *pFiguraGeometrica);
    coleccion.setColeccionAt(1, *pFiguraGeometrica1);
    coleccion.setColeccionAt(2, *pFiguraGeometrica2);
    coleccion.setColeccionAt(3, *pFiguraGeometrica3);

    for(int i=0; i<coleccion.getCantidad(); i++){
        if(dynamic_cast<Polygon*>(coleccion.getColeccionAt(i))!=0){
            cout<< coleccion.getColeccionAt(i)->area()<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<< coleccion.getColeccionAt(i)->semi()<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que me da un error, el cual dice

> [Error] cannot declare variable 'elps' to be of abstract type 'Elipse'
>   variable

Lo mismo para crcl.
Intenté incluir el virtual int semi() en la clase FiguraGeometrica, pero el error además de salir el error anterior, también sale para rect y trgl. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es reproducible con este código:

```
class Elipse
{
    virtual int semi() = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Elipse elps;

    return 0;
}
```

Que lanza el siguiente error (compilado con gcc):

> ```
> error: cannot declare variable 'elps' to be of abstract type 'Elipse'
> Elipse elps;
>        ^
> note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Elipse':
> class Elipse
>       ^~~~~~
> note:     'virtual int Elipse::semi()'
> virtual int semi() = 0;
>             ^~~~
> ```

Te está indicando que la clase `Elipse` es abstracta y por ese mismo motivo no se pueden crear instancias. Es abstracta porque tiene funciones virtuales puras, en este caso la función `semi`.

Si eliminas la función `semi` o haces que no sea virtual pura tu código no te dará este problema.

#### A tener en cuenta:

Revisa un poco más tu código porque tienes algunas cosas que no tienen sentido:

```
radio==semieje_a==semieje_b;
```

En la línea anterior seguramente querías asignar, no comparar:

```
radio=semieje_a=semieje_b;
```

Un círculo se define por un punto y un radio, una elipse por dos puntos y el radio, no tiene sentido que el círculo reciba más parámetros que una elipse:

```
Elipse elps(6,4);
Circulo crcl(3,3,3);
```